# How to Set a textbox value in a new opened window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following div with a textbox in it.

```
<div id="DvPrint">
    <div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 100px;
                                    margin-left: 25px;" class="textbox" id="ctl00_content_TxtLetterNumber" readonly="readonly" name="ctl00$content$TxtLetterNumber">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Now I write the div contents in a new window using `window.open.`

```
 n = window.open('M80Print.aspx', '_blank', 'status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,height=550px,width=640px');
            n.document.open();
 n.document.write($('#DvPrint').html());
```

Now I want to change the textbox value in new opened window. How can I do it??
Something like this:

```
n.document.getElementById('ctl00_content_TxtLetterNumber').innerHTML = "1";
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n.document.getElementById('ctl00_content_TxtLetterNumber').value = "1";
```

Changing textbox value is being done with `value`, not with `innerHTML`.

**jQuery:**

```
$('#ctl00_content_TxtLetterNumber', n.document).val('1');
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I typically work with jquery. How can I do it using jquery??

Comment: @RaymondMorphy. Updated. Though I'm not sure jQuery can work with the child window.

Comment: but it is located in the other window. I want to change it from the first window.as like as `n.document.getElementById('ctl00_content_TxtLetterNumber').innerHTML = "1";`
' but using jquery.

Comment: @RaymondMorphy. `jQuery` can't do everything, can it make you a coffee? it's an abstraction library above javascript, it shouldn't and can't replace vanilla javascript.

Comment: No. but jquery is powerful. I wish it could.

Comment: `$('#ctl00_content_TxtLetterNumber', n.document)` should do the trick. @Raymond: I recommend to spend some time going through http://api.jquery.com/ and get familiar with the methods. That will save you a lot of time...

Comment: @FelixKling. it might, but I wouldn't use it... what's wrong with javascript? I updated. thanks

Comment: Nothing is wrong with JavaScript... but since the question is tagged with jQuery and it is possible to do so, why not include it? :)

Comment: @FelixKling. True but when you are asked to change `this` value, `$(this).val('foo')` is a bad answer, no matter if the question tag is `jQuery` or not... `:)`

Comment: That is true... I don't like the over-obsessive use of jQuery either.